# list.append() automatically updates dictionary values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, append

Does anyone know why my dictionary updated automatically even though I didn't use the dict.update() method?

```
fruits = { "green" : ["kiwi"] }

name = "avocado"    
list_tmp = fruits.get("green")
list_tmp.append(name)

print(fruits)

# output:
 {'green': ['kiwi', 'avocado']}
```

Comment: The most bizarre thing is that you get `"strawberry"` from `"avocado"`.

Comment: Your output makes no sense. I suspect you would actually get `{'green': ['kiwi', 'avocado']}`

Comment: In any case, the issue is that `list_tmp` is a shallow copy of `fruits["green"]`, which means that modifying one will modify the other. What you probably want is something like `list_tmp = fruits.get("green").copy()`

Comment: Where did you first type strawberry inside your code?

Comment: What would you like to be your output?

Comment: `list_tmp` is not a shallow copy; it's a *reference* to the same list. A shallow copy would be a *new* list containing the same references as the old list. (And a deep copy would be a new list with copies of the values in the old list.)

Comment: The dictionary did not change at all, it still has identical keys and values.

Comment: @StSav012 Sorry, I got the fruits wrong, the post has been edited :)

Comment: @Math I expected that the values in the dictionary would not change, i.e. fruits = { 'green' : ['kiwi'] }

Answer (score 1):

In Python, both `dict` and `list` are mutable. This means that whenever you alter `list_tmp`, you change `fruits`.

`fruits.get("green")` returns not a copy of the list, but the list itself. Then you change the list. The item of the dictionary “points” to an altered list now.

Answer (score -1):

In order to make changes on a copy of your dictionary follow the code below:

```
import copy


fruits = { "green" : ["kiwi"] }
fruits2=copy.deepcopy(fruits)
name = "avocado"    
list_tmp = fruits2["green"]
list_tmp.append(name)
```

Comment: `copy.deepcopy` is quite expensive and in general a performance hit to use it when it can be avoided. here, I think it can be, because you dont actually need to clone the `dict` object itself. For performance wise I think it would be much better like `fruits['green'].copy()` instead.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Yes, I agree with you. It is wise advice. Therefore I am going to edit the answer to include your answer if you don't have any problems (copyright permission (: )

Comment: it’s fine by me, sure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).